# Lifetime of unread push notification

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

Hello guys this is  simple question for anyone that already know this.

I just want to know, once i send a push notification to an IOS device, how long does it lasts in his screen while the IOS device is in sleep mode? It is important for the design of my app.

If they dissapear even if they have not been read, then i'll have to push at a different time.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

20 seconds, if you have not received another notification.

Comment: Thanks1 is there any supporting document? I can't find it in the "Local and Push Notification Programming Guide"